# How to add a plus sign before a variable in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsx

I'm trying to add a plus sign before a phone number. This is my attempt, however, nothing is set to the database using this:

```
var phone = this.state.phone;
var phone2 = `+ ${phone}`
db.ref(`${serial}`).set({
    phone2,
)}
```

What is wrong with this method and is there a better way to add a plus before a variable?

Many thanks!

Edit:
I'm using a library for the input:

```
<PhoneInput
          inputExtraProps={{
            name: "phone",
            required: true,
            autoFocus: true
          }}
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
        />
```

Function that saves to state:

```
handlePhoneChange = value => {
        this.setState({ phone: value }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.phone);
        });
      };
```

Is it possible that I'm setting something wrong in the above mentioned code, because different ways to concatenate a plus (such as "+" + phone) aren't working?
Without the plus everything works fine and is saved to the database.

The library used for the phone input is: react-phone-input-2.

Comment: Try This: `"+ " + phone`

Comment: Fwiw, it adds a plus and a space. There's nothing wrong with this method. The code isn't specific to React at all. And the reason something isn't added to db is unknown. The question lacks necessary details. Make sure phone2 is a proper field name.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal thanks for your suggestion. It still doesn't work. Could you check the edit I made.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for your reply. I made an edit, since the problem might be in my other functions.

Comment: Please mention what library your using for the PhoneInput component. It may be a restriction/option on that component?

Comment: @Daantje I'm using the react-phone-input-2 library.

Comment: Try to debug your values with a breakpoint, `debugger` statement or console.log (should be used as the last resort). Troubleshooting in the dark is frustrating. This is something you can do on your end, otherwise consider provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The validation of react-phone-input-2 removes the + from the value in the default setup.

Check the options: https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2#other-props

You could use the `prefix` option, like this:

```
<PhoneInput 
          prefix="+"
          inputExtraProps={{
            name: "phone",
            required: true,
            autoFocus: true

          }}
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the plus still doesn't appear in front of the number. I will try to search for another solution in the documentation.

Comment: Than it looks like you want a (custom) mask. Or the `state.phone` is being altered by an other piece of code, like the method called `onChange`?